# RHEL5 Minimal Installation

Tags: redhat, installation, rhel5

I've got my server hosted at theplanet, and I'm trying to get them to do a minimal install of RHEL5 (64bit).  Here's what anaconda-ks.cfg shows:

```
install
url --url http://192.168.0.2/RHES5-x86_64
key --skip
lang en_US.UTF-8
.
.
.
selinux --enforcing
timezone --utc America/Chicago
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda,sdb
# The following is the partition information you requested
# Note that any partitions you deleted are not expressed
# here so unless you clear all partitions first, this is
# not guaranteed to work
#clearpart --linux --drives=sda
#part /boot --fstype ext3 --onpart sda1
#part / --fstype ext3 --onpart sda2
#part /data --fstype ext3 --onpart sda5
#part swap --onpart sda3

%packages
@core
```

Now, I would guess this would install a minimal number of packages.  However,  rpm -qa | wc -l gives a total of 614 packages installed.  Going through the install.log, I see packages related to sound, dvd rw, bluetooth, printing, XOrg packages, etc.  Reading online a bit, I'm seeing that a minimal install should be more like 250-280 packages.

Any thoughts on how to strip this down further?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add --nobase to your %packages stanza, like this:

```
%packages --nobase
```

That'll mean you *really* need to know what you are doing though, as only the absolute minimum of packages will be installed. You *need* @core if you do this, and probably some more packages too. If you add --nodocs (or --nodoc, I'm not sure), you'll even skip installing the %doc section of individual RPM's, saving even more space.